# Numeric integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, physics, numerical-integration

I want to do a numerical integration of the following equation in Matlab.

[image: Equation]

For simplicity, lets pretend that only the second fraction of the equation is there.

And this is what I have tried so far:

```
for lambda=280:2500  
  numerator(lambda) = trapz(Einc(lambda:lambda+1)*St(lambda));
  denominator(lambda) = trapz(Eref(lambda:lambda+1)*St(lambda));
end
Fraction= nansum(numerator)/ nansum(denominator);
```

St is not defined in the entire 280-2500 range, that is why I use nansum at the end. But overall I feel that what I’m doing is wrong and that there should be a much more normal and correct way of calculating this, yet I have tried googling this and asked on Mathworks forum as well but no one answers me even though this should be a pretty common thing to calculate… Could someone please help me how do write this formula?

Comment: You don't need to use a `for` loop with `trapz`. You should define an `x`-vector first, e.g. `x=280:2500`, then define a `y`-vector, e.g. `y = x.^2`. Then `rough_int = trapz(x,y)` is a numeric estimate of the integral.

Comment: You mean like this?

x=1:2200;
y =Einc.*St;
rough_int = trapz(x,y)

It gives me the error message:
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Because St is of a different size than Einc, and furthermore it is not defined at all places that Einc is, that is why I used nansum to begin with.

Comment: I am wondering about your definition for `Einc` and `St`. Why don't they have the same length as `x`? How do they depend on `x`? If any of them are not defined over the integration interval, isn't the integral undefined as well? If they have the same length as `x` and if you can safely ignore `nan`s (dangerous!), you can can use `good_indexes = ~isnan(St) & ~isnan(Einc); x_good = x(good_indexes); St_good = ...` and so on.

Comment: What I have done now is defined two versions of Eref and Einc: One Eref1&Einc1 which are cropped so that they only contain values between 305-2500. And the second version Eref2&Einc2&St are cropped in the interval 280-2500. This way if I understand correctly I don’t have to enter integration limits, trapz integrates the entire thing. I also replaced all NaNs inside St with zeroes, this way the integration won’t give me any error but undefined values in St are still not impacting the integration. Is this correct? SMMF=(trapz(Eref1)/trapz(Einc1))*(trapz((Einc2.*St2))/trapz((Eref2.*St2)))

Comment: What exactly are `Eref`, `Einc` and `St`?

Comment: Einc is incident energy/radiation in the form of an electromagnetic spectrum, Eref is a reference spectrum and St is a spectral response curve describing how valuable each wavelength is. The integration limits corresponds to different wavelengths.